# host command not resolving reverse lookup zone using secondary dns entry

Tags: linux, dns

I am using two dns entries

```
nameserver x.x.x.x
nameserver y.y.y.y
```

where x.x.x.x is ip for domain1 and y.y.y.y is ip for domain2

i am using host command for reverse lookup.

```
host domain1 gives 2 ip's a and b 
host domain2 gives 2 ip's c and d
```

now when i do

```
host a
```

it gives me reverse lookup but

```
host c
```

doesnot .

Does host command reverse lookup works only with primary DNS and not with Secondary DNS. I have taken wireshark captures and seen no request is going to secondary dns for failed case.

Whatever i have read about it /etc/resolver works in the following way:

You should have all the DC's which you want to resolve be resolvable using primary dns and forwarders in it. From DNS you can get two types of errors
    NXDOMAIN
    Timeout
NXDOMAIN is when your dns authoritatively says that i cannot find this domain and then it does not searches further. When you get timeout from primary dns resolver then continue and tries to resolve using secondary dns.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which nameservers specified in `/etc/resolv.conf` are used is undefined. Usually the first one will be used first and subsequent ones will be used if the previous ones fail to respond, but you can't count on that.

In any case, each of the resolvers you list in `/etc/resolv.conf` should have the same view of DNS and should produce the same answer to a given question.

If your resolvers are only able to resolve some domains and not others, you should fix that problem.

Comment: The way i have setup is i need two DNS servers resolving two different domain. I cannot add forwarders in DNS. i am just not sure that why nslookup/host are going to secondary DNS for forward lookup but not for reverse lookup ?

Comment: If each resolver is not capable of resolving names in both of your two different domains, that is an error in the DNS configuration. If you need to unify two different views of DNS on your resolvers, you need to do it with forwarders and stub zones – and do it the same way on all resolvers that are part of the same set used by clients. Anything else, and you will inevitably encounter erratic behaviour and unsolvable problems like this.